# Android: Disable checkboxes without graphical change?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Is it possible to do the ***-subject-***?
Right now if I set `checkboxInstance.setEnabled(false);` the checkbox gets its "disabled graphics", grayed out and more transparent. What I am trying to do is exactly the same, but I need to keep the checkbox active-looking.

The reason for this is that I have an onClickListener on the parent element. That works alright but seems like when the checkbox is touched, the checkbox gets un/checked without firing off the listener of the parent (and of course I would like to fire that always).

Thanks!

EDIT: Basically I am looking for something like this (code in AS3, of course there is no graphics so it wouldn't really work ...but just the theory):

```
var s:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cb:Sprite = new Sprite(); //let's assume this is a checkbox

s.addChild(cb); //cb is inside of the s
addChild(s); //s is added to the display list

s.mouseChildren = false;
s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fireClick);

//cb could have a mouse listener as well, nothing would happen as s.mouseChildren is set to false
```

Comment: I'm not too much into Android, but I think you could write a custom view extending from the checkbox and override the onClick event to not change the state of the bubble, but instead pass it on to its parent (by calling `performClick` on it).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Gosh, so easy... `setClickable(false)` or `android:clickable="false"`. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is possible. When user change state of that checkbox call that code :

```
yourcheckbox.setChecked(true);
```

or

```
yourcheckbox.setChecked(false);
```